# Cloudwatch CPUUtilization metric for EC2 not showing for 5 mins interval in the cloudwatch console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have configured cloudwatch agent to send data every 5 mins for CPU, Memory, Network and Disk in an EC2 instance. Below is my config.

```
"agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "run_as_user": "root"
},
"metrics": {
    "append_dimensions": {
        "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}",
        "InstanceType": "${aws:InstanceType}"
    },
    "metrics_collected": {
        "cpu": {
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ],
            "measurement": [
                "cpu_usage_idle",
                "cpu_usage_iowait",
                "cpu_usage_user",
                "cpu_usage_system"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "totalcpu": false
        },
        "disk": {
            "measurement": [
                "used_percent",
                "inodes_free"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        "mem": {
            "measurement": [
                "mem_used_percent"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        "net": {
            "measurement": [
                "bytes_sent",
                "bytes_recv",
                "packets_sent",
                "packets_recv"
            ],
            "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
            "resources": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Restarted the cloudwatch agent and tried to see the graph for AWS/EC2 CPUUtilization in the cloudwatch console with 5 min interval set, but the graph shows empty and no data in sight. But when I turn up the interval to 15 mins, I see data in the graph. Can someone please help me understand what am I missing?